# Check if server current timezone is DST enabled

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to build a python script that exports a few server metrics to logstash. I can't seem to make it work with different timezones that have daylight savings enabled. The code keeps returning the same time with or without DST enabled. My current code is this:

```
def get_formatted_tz():
    tz = str.format('{0:05.2f}', float(time.timezone) / 3600 - time.daylight).replace('.', ':')
    return  '-' + tz if time.timezone > 0 else '+' + tz
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
formatted = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
tz = self.get_formatted_tz()
isodate = formatted + tz
```

How can I improve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've spotted one issue unrelated to your question... you're converting a float to a time by replacing the `.` with a `:`. That's not going to do what you want. As for the issue you're actually asking about, please provide an example to illustrate the undesired behavior.

Comment: @glibdud I'm a beginner when it comes to python and I have to export the time in a ISO8601 format. I wasn't able to accomplish that with the time library alone, so I ended up doing this hackish conversion.
An example would be: my server is currently on BRST (UTC-2 / Brazilian Savings Time), but the exported time is always BRT (UTC-3 / Brazilian Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched around a little more and found the answer. I was using only the time lib, now I'm using datetime.

Local to ISO-8601:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
```

UTC to ISO-8601:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```